# How is running a script like an executable different from running it by a shell explicitly?

Tags: bash

1. From [A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell
   Programming  By Mark G. Sobell](https://books.google.com/books?id=xplXdW9R6QoC&lpg=PT447&dq=shell%20subshell%20command%20execute&pg=PT447#v=onepage&q=shell%20subshell%20command%20execute&f=false)

   > Although you can use bash to execute a shell script, this technique causes the script to run more slowly than giving yourself
   >   execute permission and directly invoking the script.

   Why is that?
2. How is running a script like an executable different from running it
   by a shell explicitly?
3. Do both follow the same steps as:

   > A command on the command line causes the shell to fork a new process,
   >   creating a duplicate of the shell process (a subshell). The new
   >   process attempts to exec (execute) the command. Like fork, the exec
   >   routine is executed by the operating system (a system call). Because
   >   the command is a shell script, exec fails. When exec fails, the
   >   command is assumed to be a shell script, and the subshell runs the
   >   commands in the script. Unlike a login shell, which expects input from
   >   the command line, the subshell takes its input from a file—namely, the
   >   shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the script is a Bash script (i.e. it begins with `#!/bin/bash`), then the author is wrong on this point.  When you run a shell script directly, the kernel sees the `#!/bin/bash` line at the beginning, then runs that line with the script's filename as a parameter, i.e. `/bin/bash myscript.sh`.  In other words, the kernel is doing exactly what you would do to pass it to a shell explicitly.

Now, if the script begins with `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`, then there's another possibility.  Bash can provide `/bin/sh`, but it doesn't have to.  It also prioritizes features over size or speed.  If a smaller, faster shell is your `/bin/sh`, then running the script directly will use that faster shell, and the script will run faster than it would under Bash.

This happens in practice with Debian-based distributions (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu, Mint).  They tend to use a shell called `dash` to provide `/bin/sh` instead of Bash, in order to make the boot scripts run faster.

To see what your distribution does, `ls -l /bin/sh`.  It is probably a symbolic link to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash`, or another shell.

Comment: And the TL;DR of `#!` can be found at http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ (spoiler: it's complicated)