# How is a bash script executed via its filename as command name with and without shebang?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shebang

From bash manual:

> 3.7.2 Command Search and Execution
>
> After a command has been split into words, if it results in a simple
>   command and an optional list of arguments, the following actions are
>   taken.
>
> ...
>
> 3. If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, Bash searches each element of $PATH for a directory
>      containing an executable file by that name.
> 4. If the search is successful, or if the command name contains one or more slashes, the shell executes the named program in a separate
>      execution environment. Argument 0 is set to the name given, and the
>      remaining arguments to the command are set to the arguments supplied,
>      if any.
> 5. If this execution fails because the file is not in executable format, and the file is not a directory, **it is assumed to be a shell
>      script** and **the shell executes it as described in Section 3.8 [Shell
>      Scripts], page 39.**

1. Suppose a bash script `myscript` doesn't contain a shebang.

   - Does the quote mean that if the script is executed in bash via    command `myscript`, then

     - bash will first assume it is an ELF and calls `execve()` on it, and because it is a bash script not ELF, `execve()` call will fail,
     - bash will next execute `bash myscript`?
   - Compared to running a bash script via `bash myscript` in bash, running the script via `myscript` in bash will additionally have a
     failure call to `execve()` on the script directly?
   - If yes, is `myscript` slower than `bash myscript`?  Why does "[A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming By
     Mark G. Sobell](https://books.google.com/books?id=xplXdW9R6QoC&lpg=PT447&dq=shell%20subshell%20command%20execute&pg=PT447#v=onepage&q=shell%20subshell%20command%20execute&f=false)" say the opposite?

     > Although you can use bash to execute a shell script, this technique causes the script to run more slowly than giving yourself
     >   execute permission and directly invoking the script.
2. If a bash script `myscript` contains a shebang `#! /bin/bash`, when
   it is executed in bash via command `myscript`,

   - is it executed in the same way as it is executed in bash via command `bash myscript`?
   - is it executed in the same way as the shebang were removed from the script and  then the script were executed via command `myscript`
     ?

Thanks.

My post is inspired by [How is running a script like an executable different from running it by a shell explicitly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254709/674) and [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang#comment794568_373229)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. - > Does the quote mean that if the script is executed in bash via command myscript, then
     >
     > - bash will first assume it is an ELF and calls `execve()` on it, and because it is a bash script not ELF, `execve()` call will fail,

     If Bash finds an executable file, it will first assume that it is in some format the operating system can execute and [call `execve` on it](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5470). In the event that that succeeds, this still might not be an ELF or other native executable file. For example, [Linux's `binfmt_misc` feature allows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) many other executable formats to run. In this particular case, the `execve` call will most likely fail.

     > - bash will next execute `bash myscript`?

     [Bash will use its existing subprocess to execute the script within it, reinitialising the shell environment as necessary](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n5564). There is not an additional process launched or `exec` call.
   - > Compared to running a bash script via bash myscript in bash, running the script via myscript in bash will additionally have a failure call to `execve()` on the script directly?

     Yes, I suppose so, if you mean "a failed call".
   - > If yes, is `myscript` slower than `bash myscript`? Why does "A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming By Mark G. Sobell" say the opposite?
     >
     > > Although you can use bash to execute a shell script, this technique causes the script to run more slowly than giving yourself execute permission and directly invoking the script.

     Mindful of prevailing libel laws, I won't comment on the second part of that question, but even several failed library & system calls are not going to make a measurable difference compared to the launch of an entire `bash` process and then *interpreting* a script. I can't access the page in question to find any context you might have missed out. It almost certainly isn't discussing the shebangless case, however.
2. > If a bash script `myscript` contains a shebang `#! /bin/bash`, when it is executed in bash via command `myscript`,
   >
   > - is it executed in the same way as it is executed in bash via command `bash myscript`?

   Yes; in one case, `bash myscript` is `exec`ed directly by the subprocess, and in the other the system `exec`s `/bin/bash myscript` once it finds the shebang line.

   > - is it executed in the same way as the shebang were removed from the script and then the script were executed via command `myscript` ?

   In so far as you can reasonably detect, yes. None of this matters. Strictly, the `main()` function of `bash` doesn't run again in this case, because the subprocess just reinitialises itself internally, and it does run in the other situation. You could construct a scenario where this matters if you were really keen, but it isn't worth the effort.

Note that this is a Bash functionality, and [other shells execute shebangless scripts with `sh` or some other shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/73093), rather than either `bash` or themselves, as noted in the other question you linked. We're also assuming that your interactive shell is the same `bash` as the one in your shebang lines.

Comment: Thanks. When a call to `execve()` finishes, does `execve()` terminate its process, regardless whehter `execve()` succeeds or fails? I thought yes, so when `execve()` fails to execute a shell script, it would terminate the subprocess, and the original shell will have to fork a subprocess to execute the script.

Comment: No, it doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks.When a bash script `./test.sh` with shebang `#! /bin/bash` is executed via command `./test.sh`, is it actually executed as `/bin/bash ./test.sh`? If yes,  is it correct to expect bash to run `execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "./test.sh"], ...) = 0`? But I run `strace -f  ./test.sh 2>&1 | less`, and only find one call to `execve()`:  `execve("./test.sh", ["./test.sh"], [/* 59 vars */]) = 0`. Note the difference in the first argument, which is for the executable file.

Comment: @Tim, see [What exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268766/86440).