# What kinds of executable formats do the files under /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/ allow?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, executable, binfmt

I following [Michael's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439390/674)  to see what executable formats my Ubuntu can recognize to execute

```
$ ls -l /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 19 16:11 cli
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 19 16:11 jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 19 16:11 python2.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 19 16:11 python3.5
--w------- 1 root root 0 Apr 19 16:11 register
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 19 16:11 status
```

I have never intentionally changed anything there, and the files were created by default or when I installed some other programs.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/cli
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags: 
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

What kind of executable format is this? I googled "magic 4d5a" and found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable, but I am not sure how the file was created there since it is not a native executable format to Linux. Did installation of `wine` add it?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/jar
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/lib/jexec
flags: 
offset 0
magic 504b0304
```

Is the above for JVM bytecode format?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/python3.5 
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
flags: 
offset 0
magic 160d0d0a
```

Is the above for Python bytecode or Python?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status
enabled

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register 
cat: /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Permission denied
```

What is `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register` used for? Does it also allow some executable format?

Does ELF format need a file under `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [How is Mono magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440) for more background. `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` is a virtual file system managed by `binfmt_misc` (which is why the files are all 0-sized).

`cli` is used for Windows and .NET executables (and really any MZ executable, as also used in DOS and OS/2); the detector it refers to determines whether a given binary should be run using Wine or Mono.

`jar` provides support for JAR files, as used by Java programs. You can thus make a JAR executable, and run it directly (instead of using `java -jar ...`).

The `python` files provide support for Python bytecode.

`status` shows the overall status of `binfmt_misc`: in this case, it’s enabled.

`register` allows new formats to be registered. This is done by echoing a string in a specific format (see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) for details) to `register`. The registered format will show up as a new file alongside `cli`, `jar` and the others.

Many kinds of executable formats can be registered using `binfmt_misc`. They can be matched using a file extension (`.jar` etc., although JAR files are identified by their “PK” signature instead) or a magic value (“MZ” etc.), as long as the magic value occurs within the first 128 bytes. Beyond the files you’ve listed, other formats typically handled in this way are binaries for other architectures (“interpreted” by QEMU, or emulators such as Hatari), some interpreted game formats (the `love` game engine registers itself in this fashion under Debian at least)...

Under Debian and derivatives, packages register binary formats using [`binfmt-support`](https://tracker.debian.org/binfmt-support) and files in `/usr/share/binfmts/cli`; `dlocate -S /usr/share/binfmts/*` will tell you which packages are adding binary formats.

ELF doesn’t need any registration, it’s supported natively by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks. What are the differences between magic word set up by binfmt_misc  and shebang, from the perspective of calling `execve()`? Can the first argument to `execve()` be either a file containing   a magic word set up by binfmt_misc, or a file containing a shebang? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439376/how-is-a-bash-script-executed-via-its-filename-as-command-name-with-and-without#comment795018_439390

Comment: See [the `execve` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html): the first argument can point to either a binary executable, or a script starting with a shebang. What constitutes a binary executable is determined by the kernel: in Linux, binaries are supported by one of the `binfmt_` modules, which include `a.out`, ELF, `em86` (on Alpha), flat files, “misc” (as in `binfmt_misc`), and scripts with a shebang. (So the Linux *implementation* treats scripts in the same way as binaries.)

Comment: Thanks. "in Linux, binaries are supported by one of the binfmt_ modules, which include a.out, ELF, em86 (on Alpha), flat files, “misc” (as in binfmt_misc), and scripts with a shebang." (1) What  do you mean  by `a.out` ? Do you mean ELF? When `gcc my.c`, it generates `a.out`, which has ELF format. (2) What does " flat files" mean? I heard that flat files are text files in database like scenario (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database), but not sure that is what you meant (3) What does “misc” as in `binfmt_misc` mean?  (4) What is the source/reference for the sentence?

Comment: The reference is [the kernel source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs) (see also [the configuration descriptions](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/Kconfig.binfmt)). `a.out` means [a.out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), the old executable format. (And yes, many C compilers use `a.out` as their default target name, independently of the format...) “Flat files” refers to the uClinux binary format.

Comment: (5) "binaries are supported by one of the `binfmt_ `modules".  What other `binfmt_` modules besides `binfmt_misc`? `lsmod  | grep binfmt_` and `locate binfmt_` only show `binfmt_misc`.

Comment: You won’t find other `binfmt` modules in most systems; for example, current Debian kernels build ELF and script support into the kernel, `binfmt_misc` as a module, and nothing else.

Comment: (3) I can't find out what “misc” (as in binfmt_misc) means as a binary executable file formt. I don't know what it is.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) (also linked in the answer): “misc” stands for “miscellaneous”, and there is no single miscellaneous binary format — `binfmt_misc` provides support for miscellaneous binary formats, that’s why it’s named that way.

Comment: Thanks. Stephen. I'd appreciate also if you could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416969/is-a-registered-custom-executable-format-also-described-by-an-object-of-type-li?noredirect=1#comment91778309_52416969