# What types of executable files exist on Linux?

Tags: linux, executable

For example, if I do

```
[OP@localhost executable]$ cat garbage 
lalala
trololol
[OP@localhost executable]$ chmod +x garbage
[OP@localhost executable]$ ./garbage 
./garbage: line 1: lalala: command not found
./garbage: line 2: trololol: command not found
```

Bash seems to be trying to interpret this "executable" as a script. However, there are two instances where this clearly does not happen: when the file begins with a `#!`, and ELF files. Are there any more? Is there a comprehensive documentation of this somewhere?

Comment: You can add pretty much anything as an executable using [binfmt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc)

Comment: Not only `bash` does that, but any program which is trying to run an executable file via `execvp(2)` or `execlp(2)` (eg. try `xargs <garbage ./garbage`). That's required by the POSIX standard.

Comment: In addition to what @mosvy says, IIRC the difference is that other programs try to run it using `sh`, but bash tries to run it itself irrespective of what `sh` is. (compare a script with `echo $BASH_VERSION $_`, ran with `bash -c ./foo.sh`, `dash -c ./foo.sh` and `echo foo | xargs ./foo.sh`

Comment: Highly related: [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/73093)

Comment: Also a sequence of interesting Tim questions around [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439569/73093).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on [my previous comment on another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439569/what-kinds-of-executable-formats-do-the-files-under-proc-sys-fs-binfmt-misc-al#comment795348_439583), the kernel [contains seven binary loaders](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs) (look for files starting with `binfmt_` there, or read [the `binfmt`-specific `Kconfig`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/Kconfig.binfmt)):

- `a.out` (which is currently [on a stay of execution](https://lwn.net/Articles/782511/));
- ELF;
- FDPIC ELF (on ARM, MMU-less SuperH, and C6x);
- `em86` (on Alpha);
- flat binaries (on MMU-less systems, or ARM, or M68k);
- scripts;
- [the almighty `binfmt_misc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440) (see also [What kinds of executable formats do the files under /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/ allow?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439569/86440)).

These are what determine the types of executable files that the kernel can execute. `binfmt_misc` in particular allows many other binaries to be handled by the kernel (at least, from the perspective of the process calling [one of the `exec` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html)).

However this doesn’t cover the whole story, since the C library and shells themselves are also involved. POSIX now requires that the `execlp` and `execvp` functions, when they encounter an executable which the kernel can’t run, try running it using a shell; see [the rationale here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html#tag_16_111_08) for details.

The way all this interacts to provide the behaviour you’re seeing is detailed in [What exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268766/86440) and [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/86440)