# fork(), exec() sequence with object file formats?

Tags: exec, fork

It's my understanding that POSIX systems rely on certain linker formats to organize memory during a `fork()` `exec()` sequence of calls.  a.out, COFF and ELF are widely known formats of binary object files used by OSs.

Does anyone know generally where the code is that reads these in the `fork()` `exec()` sequence?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The `exec()` call takes a filename which will hopefully be in a format that is understood by the operating system. This includes shell scripts as well as ELF etc. Linux allows you to extend this list with the binfmt_misc filesystem giving an easy interface.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no general answer, although in most POSIX-like systems, the kernel handles at least some parts of loading executables and setting them up in memory.

In Linux (which isn’t a certified POSIX system, but POSIX-like), the kernel loaders for the executable formats it supports are in [the `fs` directory of the kernel sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs), in the files with names starting with `binfmt_`. See [What types of executable files exist on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511790/86440) for more details.

In macOS (which is a certified POSIX system), the loaders are in [`bsd/kern/kern_exec.c` in the Darwin source](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/master/bsd/kern/kern_exec.c), in the various `exec_*_imgact` functions.

In OpenBSD, the loaders are in [`sys/kern`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/tree/master/sys/kern), in the `exec_*` files; [`exec_elf.c`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/sys/kern/exec_elf.c) handles ELF executables.