# Executable common files (*.pdf, etc.)

Tags: csv, pdf, executable, file-types

I have a number of files showing up green when I run `ls`. I understand these are executables, and I understand that one can make a file executable with `chmod`. But they are `.csv` and `.pdf` files. I don't understand how one could 'execute' a comma-separated text file or a PDF. So:

- How can they actually be 'executable'?
- And how would I execute them?
- And what would happen when I did?

Comment: Most probably happened while you copied those files from a FAT32 or NTFS, normal thing.

Comment: Interesting. I think 'why' warrants it's own question. Has it already been asked?

Comment: [Permission to execute](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183994/understanding-unix-permissions-and-file-types/183999) does not mean that the file is an ["executable"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511790/what-types-of-executable-files-exist-on-linux). Most likely executing the file will give an error. [See also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268766/what-exactly-happens-when-i-execute-a-file-in-my-shell) and [also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156392/what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-exe-file).

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Yup. Happens as a matter of course when I copy photos from an SD card.

Comment: Incidentally, *directories* normally need to have the executable bit set. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/88378

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just a question of *permissions*. If a file has execute permissions, that just means users are *allowed* to execute it. Whether they will be successful is another matter. In order for a file to be executed, the user executing it must have the right to do so *and* the file needs to be a valid executable. The permissions shown by `ls` only affect the first part, permission, and have no bearing on the rest.

For instance:

```
$ cat file.csv
a,silly,file
$ chmod a+x file.csv
$ ls -l file.csv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 terdon terdon 13 May 29 15:22 file.csv
```

This file now has execute permissions (see the 3 `x` in the permissions string `-rwxr-xr-x`). But if I try to execute it, I will get an error:

```
$ ./file.csv 
./file.csv: line 1: a,silly,file: command not found
```

That is because the shell is trying to execute the file as a shell script, and there are no valid shell commands in it, so it fails.

Comment: In your example, you shell succeeded at launching a `sh` interpreter to interpret that file, and that sh interpreter succeeded at interpreting that file (interpreting all the lines in that file as `sh`s do interpret and run code as they read it) as it was in valid `sh` syntax, but it failed to find the `a,silly,file` command. As that was the only line in that file, the exit status was `127`, so a failure exit status.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, exactly. Am I saying something that would contradict that? The shell is trying to execute the "commands" found in the "script", as it should, and fails since there is no valid command.

Comment: terdon, I think @StéphaneChazelas point is that the csv file was actually executed. The fact that the csv file caused an error during its execution does not negate that the csv was executed. This seems a matter of semantics as you could also argue that it is only the sh interpreter that is executing. Suffice it to say, your primary point of the file permission is separate from it being a file able to be executed is correct. Coming up with an example that no-one on the internet will respond with "Well actually..." is difficult when the definition of what is executing is so blurry.

Comment: run my executable CSV. The first line is `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 7):

The green in your `ls` display means that the files have execute *permissions*, which doesn't necessarily mean that they can be *executed* in any way.

If you accidentally set the execute permission, or if it was set due to an import from a file system without support for the basic linux permission model, you can remove the execute bit with

```
chmod a-x -- "$filename"
```

and that file will no longer show as "executable".

---

Note that other colors in the file listing *may* be set based on file extension; but in this case it is likely just the permission bits.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer perpetuates myths and a poor understanding of how "executing" a file happens in Unix.

`./cmd` in the shell does more than just trying to execute `./cmd`: if executing `./cmd` fails with `ENOEXEC` (as it does for any executable file which is not a valid **binary** or doesn't start with a **shebang**, including a valid shell script) then the shell will either **a.** read and interpret itself the file as a shell script or **b.** execute `/bin/sh` or another shell and pass it `./cmd` as its first argument.

The shebang mechanism (`#! /path/to/interpreter`), though implemented by most Unix systems, is not standard. Also, many systems like Linux are also able to "execute" files starting with other "magic" sequences (or even based on their file extension, MSDOS-like).

For instance, you can have "executable" pdf files on Linux via [binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst):

```
$ chmod +x 2503.pdf
$ ./2503.pdf
./2503.pdf: line 1: fg: no job control
./2503.pdf: line 1051: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `/Linearized')
[... a lot of crazy errors in the same vein ...]

$ su -c 'echo :pdf-zathura:M::%PDF-1.::/usr/bin/zathura: > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register'
$ ./2503.pdf
[start zathura and display the pdf file]
```