# Why can my statically compiled ARM binary of BusyBox run on my x86_64 PC?

Tags: busybox, cross-compilation

Bit of a strange situation there. I compiled a static executable of BusyBox 1.32.1 for the ARM platform (32-bit) and strangely it runs without problems on both platforms. Look by yourself:

```
root@smallbuntu /m/n/b/i/n/rootfs# readelf -h bin/busybox-initrd
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1f419
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1482800 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000002, Version5 EABI, <unknown>
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         27
  Section header string table index: 26
root@smallbuntu /m/n/b/i/n/rootfs#
```

then:

```
root@smallbuntu /m/n/b/i/n/rootfs# bin/busybox-initrd ls
bin         home        media       proc        srv         var
boot        kobo        mnt         root        sys
dev         lib         modules     run         tmp
etc         lost+found  opt         sbin        usr
root@smallbuntu /m/n/b/i/n/rootfs# bin/busybox-initrd uname -a
Linux smallbuntu 5.8.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:18:36 UTC 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@smallbuntu /m/n/b/i/n/rootfs#
```

`uname -a` seems to return `armv7l` by the busybox binary. Here's the normal output:

```
Linux smallbuntu 5.8.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:18:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea of what's going on?
Thanks!

Comment: The suggested duplicate is about Mono, but the answer addresses this scenario too (`binfmt_misc` and QEMU).

Comment: Interesting question, but this is more related to the architecture it's running on.

Comment: @NicolasMailloux, same thing  though, that foreign arch file is being interpreted by something like `/usr/libexec/qemu-binfmt/arm-binfmt-P` as something has registered it for this kind of file (check in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look inside `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`, you’ll probably see a file named `qemu-arm` or something similar, with contents along the lines of

```
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
flags: OCF
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

[This instructs the kernel to “interpret” binaries](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) matching the given magic value using `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static`. This allows it to use QEMU to emulate ARM CPUs (and fix up system calls to match the ARM ABI) and run ARM binaries transparently on any system where QEMU can emulate ARM CPUs, including your 64-bit x86 PC.

In your case, since the ARM binary is statically linked, no additional setup is required. Dynamically-linked binaries need their native libraries to be available too.

On Debian-based systems, including Ubuntu-based systems, this is set up by the `qemu-user-static` and `binfmt-support` packages: the `qemu-user-static` package registers the `binfmt_misc` configurations that QEMU can handle using [`update-binfmts`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/binfmt-support/update-binfmts.8), and the `binfmt-support` package ensures that the registered configurations are loaded into the kernel (`binfmt_misc` is a kernel module).

See also [What types of executable files exist on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511790/86440), [What kinds of executable formats do the files under /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/ allow?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439569/86440), and [How is Mono magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440)

Comment: Well, you're right! That was a nice mistery solved! Thanks!

Comment: @Stéphane just a minor detail, `qemu-user-static` doesn’t need the `qemu-arm` file, it registers everything from its postint (and the configuration then ends up in `/var/lib/binfmts`).

Comment: @StephenKitt, but that's the `/usr/share/binfmts/qemu-arm` file that the postinst script imports

Comment: @Stéphane not in Debian 10, but I see [that’s changed for Debian 11](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866756). In Debian 10 `qemu-user-static`’s `postinst` calls `update-binfmt` with the specs as command-line parameters, not in files.