# Why can an aarch64 ELF executable be run on an x86_64 machine?

Tags: architecture, elf

I compiled a simple "Hello World" C program on Raspberry Pi 3, which was then transferred to an AMD64 laptop. Out of curiosity, I executed it, and it runs even though I did not expect it to:

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux 15ud490-gx76k 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bash
$ file hello64
hello64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=486ee1cde035cd704b49c037a32fb77239b6a1c2, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped
```

```bash
$ ./hello64
Hello World!
```

Like that, how can it execute?

QEMU User Emulation is installed, but I don't know whether it is playing a part in this or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

QEMU user emulation is exactly why your binary runs: on your system, one of the QEMU-related packages you’ve installed ensures that QEMU is registered as a handler for all the architectures it can emulate, and the kernel then passes binaries to it. As long as you have the required libraries, if any, the binary will run; since your binary is statically linked, it has no external dependencies.

See [Why can my statically compiled ARM binary of BusyBox run on my x86_64 PC?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/648647/86440) and [How is Mono magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440) for details.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s not QEMU that does the registration, but usually init scripts or one-shot systemd units shipped by the distro itself that do (there are also other ways this can be handled, such as the [multiarch/qemu-user-static](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static) Docker image). Ubuntu and Debian ship this in a package called `qemu-user-binfmt`, which IIRC gets pulled in by default if you install either the regular or statically linked user-mode emulation binaries, and the package enables this functionality by default when installed.

Comment: @Austin yes, or by `qemu-user-static` (see [this previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/648650/86440), also linked in the answer, for details). `qemu-user-static` does its own registration; `qemu-user-binfmt` is only used with `qemu-user`.

Comment: Note that dynamically-linked programs are not likely to work so easily. The OP's program is statically linked.

Comment: @user253751 yes; “As long as you have the required libraries, if any, the binary will run; since your binary is statically linked, it has no external dependencies.” On Debian derivatives it’s not that hard to run many dynamically-linked foreign binaries, thanks to multi-arch, but it is of course much simpler to run static binaries.